# Merge dataframes having array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have two data frames.

## DF1

```
isActive,trackedSearchId
True,53436615
True,53434228
True,53434229
```

## DF2

```
trackedSearchIds,Primary Keyword Group(s)
"[53436613, 53436615, 53437436, 53436506]",SEO - Directory-Deployment
"[53435887, 53437509, 53437441, 53436615, 53438685, 53437636]",SEO - Other-Glossary
"[53437504, 53435090, 53435887, 53434228]",SEO - Other
"[53437504, 53435090, 53434229]",SEO - Glossary
```

I want to check for each row of DF1 for column trackedSearchId and check with each row in DF2 with each value of trackedSearchIds array and if the value of DF1 column is present in DF2 append it with DF1.

## The output should look like:

```
isActive,trackedSearchId,Primary Keyword Group(s)
True,53436615,SEO - Directory-Deployment&SEO - Other-Glossary
True,53434228,SEO - Other
True,53434229,SEO - Glossary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming strings representations of lists in df2, use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), [`explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import ast

df1['trackedSearchId'] = df1['trackedSearchId'].astype(str)

out = df1.merge((df2.assign(trackedSearchIds=df2['trackedSearchIds'].str.findall(r'(\d+)')).explode('trackedSearchIds')
                    .groupby('trackedSearchIds').agg('&'.join)
               ),
               left_on='trackedSearchId', right_on='trackedSearchIds')
```

Output:

```
   isActive trackedSearchId                         Primary Keyword Group(s)
0      True        53436615  SEO - Directory-Deployment&SEO - Other-Glossary
1      True        53434228                                      SEO - Other
2      True        53434229                                   SEO - Glossary
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) of converted values to list by `ast.literal_eval` if necessary, aggregate `join` in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and append new column in [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
import ast

df = (df1.join(df2.assign(trackedSearchIds=df2['trackedSearchIds'].apply(ast.literal_eval))
           .explode('trackedSearchIds')
           .groupby('trackedSearchIds')['Primary Keyword Group(s)']
           .agg('&'.join), on='trackedSearchId'))
print (df)
   isActive  trackedSearchId                         Primary Keyword Group(s)
0      True         53436615  SEO - Directory-Deployment&SEO - Other-Glossary
1      True         53434228                                      SEO - Other
2      True         53434229                                   SEO - Glossary
```

If values are lists:

```
df = (df1.join(df2
           .explode('trackedSearchIds')
           .groupby('trackedSearchIds')['Primary Keyword Group(s)']
           .agg('&'.join), on='trackedSearchId'))
```